# Save state and parameters from an HTML canvas to a file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to save data from a canvas to a file (XML or any other type) with javascript so it can be extracted later and loaded to another canvas. I don't want to save an image (png,jpeg,etc) because I can't extract variables from those.

Comment: What is the use case for this? What variables? If this is a game for example where the canvas appears to have state the canvas itself is merely something pixels are drawn to. It is the JavaScript framework behind it that holds all the state.

Comment: Well, I want to save all the stuff from the javascript that loads the canvas into its "current position". The use case is a generic thing, from drawing a simple square to maybe a game.

Comment: This would ultimately depend entirely on the engine powering the canvas then and what it exposes for saving state, if at all. There is no generic way to point something at a canvas and save all variables some JavaScript is using to represent that canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Save canvas in to SVG image. Form svg u can extract data.

Comment: Bit that wouldn't save any engines state that is powering the canvas, which I gather from the ops comment what they want.

Comment: This could help in a certain context